# KafkaIO GroupId after restart

Tags: apache-beam-io, apache-beam-kafkaio

I am using Apache Beam's KafkaIO to read from a Kafka topic. Everything is working as expected, but if my job is terminated and restarted, there is a new groupID that is generated by the new job hence it ends up reading  from the beginning of the topic.

In other words if my initial job had **group.id = Reader-0_offset_consumer_11111111_my_group** as a groupID, the next job may end up having **group.id = Reader-0_offset_consumer_22222222_my_group** this. As you can see there is some unique prefix that gets prepended before my specified **my_group**.
Is there any way to avoid this and keep the same group id each time?
Thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?